# jQuery `find` whilst matching one class or two classes

Tags: jquery

There is a table in my site, where, on some pages, it has two classes, and on other pages it has one class.  I want to do a `find` on that table, but need to find in both cases, but I don't want to do to searches to discover the elements.

How can I write this?  (I am no expert in js nor jquery; I appreciate your help)  Here is what I've come up with so far, but it doesn't seem to work on both pages:

```
var tablerow1 = $('table [class="firstclass"]');
var tablerow2 = $('table [class="firstclass secondclass"]');

if(tablerow2){
    var tablerow = tablerow2;
}else{
    var tablerow = tablerow1;
};  

tablerow.find('tr').each(function(index, thiselement){
    ...
}
```

Comment: It would help to see the HTML that you need this to work with.

Comment: Yeah, but it is sharepoint.  The function works on the list if I use `tablerow1` OR `tablerow2` - but I need to know how to write the function in order to find either/or instead of just one of them.

Comment: Wouldn't matching on `firstclass` be sufficient, or are there other tables on the page that would have `firstclass` when the one you need has both `firstclass` and `secondclass`?

Comment: @j08691 - You would think so, but it didn't seem to work right.  Maybe it is a Sharepoint thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var tablerow1 = $('table [class="firstclass"]');
var tablerow2 = $('table [class="firstclass secondclass"]');
```

to

```
var tablerow1 = $('table.firstclass');
var tablerow2 = $('table.firstclass.secondclass');
```

But you could also just select `firstclass`. It will select tables with this class, also if it has some more other classes, so in your case, your table would be selected in both of your cases.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked (I have to wait seven minutes to accept...).  How come what I had written did not work?

Comment: Your code may also work, if you remove the spaces in your selector, for example: `table [class="firstclass"]` should be `table[class="firstclass"]`. But you don't need to select the class attribute, because a simple `.classname` is enough. This is the conventional way.